# how to access sqlite3 database from cpanel using php

Tags: php, sqlite

hi friends ,

```
         class MyDB extends SQLite3
         {
         function __construct()
          {
              $this->open('/var/cpanel/eximstats_db.sqlite3');
            }
         }
         $db = new MyDB();
         if(!$db){
         echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
         } else {
         echo "Opened database successfully\n";
         }
```

i have using eximstats db from server. while on updating my server the eximstats db get got under the SQLite3. i am new one to SQLite3 even though I have tried many more times access that db using the above php code but never i got result .  please help me to improve this coding.

Is this code is correct . while running this  i got  "Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Unable to open database: unable to open database file' "

thank you

Comment: @DavidDomain thank you for your answer . i have installed  PDO driver then it shows the Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver'

Comment: You are unable to open the database because you are trying to access the database as a non-root user, but database is owned by root and only writable by root. Try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44499844/cant-access-eximstats-sqlite3-db-after-whm64-upgrade

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use PHP PDO interface to access your SQLite3 database.

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite:/var/cpanel/eximstats_db.sqlite3')
```

> [PDO_SQLITE DSN](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.connection.php)
>
> *To access a database on disk, append the absolute path to the DSN prefix.*

Just make sure that you have the PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x installed on your system.

Now to select a table just do:

```
$result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM tablename');
foreach( $result as $row ) {
  print_r( $row );
}
```

Comment: i have tried the PDO commands but still i got error now the error is " Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' "    by using phpinfo() it shows that PDO driver enabled . what i do next

Comment: Which PHP version, OS are you using?

Comment: i have tried $db = new PDO('myservername/sqlite:/var/cpanel/eximstats_db.sqlite3'); is this  work

Comment: php version 5.6.24

Comment: You may need to install the PDO sqlite driver. Eg. `sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite` then restart apache or whatever server you are using `sudo service apache2 restart`, also make sure that you have read and write access on `/var/cpanel/eximstats_db.sqlite3`.

Comment: @ DavidDomain PDO got installed  still also i got the same error  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver'   now the running code is $db = new PDO('/var/cpanel/eximstats_db.sqlite3');
if(!$db){
echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
echo "no connection obtained";
} else {
echo "Opened database successfully\n";
}